# Backup WSL without using wsl --import or --export

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to reinstall windows on my computer but keep all the files, but I'm not sure if it'll keep or delete my installed distros. Also, I can't open a terminal and run `wsl --import` because the terminal hangs and windows ends up crashing for some reason. Is there any way to backup WSL or can I recover it after resetting?

Edit: forgot to mention I'm using WSL 2

One last thing I forgot to add, when I changed pc I backed up WSL and imported it, looking through my files it looks like I have a file called ext4.vhdx that was accessed updated yesterday. Could that be my distro and does that mean I can copy that over?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Windows installs tend to wipe out user settings (i.e. `AppData`), and the WSL files are typically installed there.  Backing up the distribution is a good idea before performing a Windows reinstall.  As you said, normally this would be done with `wsl --export/--import`, but in your case, that's not viable.

### For WSL2

Under WSL2, the entire filesystem is kept in a virtual HDD file named `ext4.vhdx`.  You can find it in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroup...\LocalState\ext4.vhdx`.  The `...` part will vary depending on the exact Ubuntu version you installed from the Store.

Back up this file before reinstalling Windows.  Make sure WSL is not running at all via a `wsl --shutdown` (assuming you can still access that command).  If you can't `wsl --shutdown`, at least reboot Windows before backing up the file, to make sure it is not in use.  You could also run in safe mode, if you really want to be sure.

After reinstalling, you *should* be able to recover by:

- Reinstalling WSL (don't forget to set your default version to 2, if desired)
- Reinstalling Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store
- Copying back in the `ext4.vhdx` over the freshly installed one.

If you have Windows Professional or higher, it might also be wise to test the `vhdx` by creating a new Ubuntu VM and attaching it (or preferably, a copy of the vhdx) as a drive.

I have copied vhdx's from one WSL installation over another before without issue, but of course there's no guarantee it's going to go perfectly.

Assuming that the `vhdx` is valid, as a fallback you could mount it as a virtual drive in a VM, copy out the necessary user files, and copy just those over your new install.

### For WSL1

For other readers who come across this and have WSL1 installations (perhaps in addition to WSL2), there's no way to back up and restore the *entire* filesystem as with WSL2.

But you can and should still backup the `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroup...\LocalState\rootfs`.  This contains the entire filesystem, so any essential files can be copied back in to your new installation.  However, it would not be safe to *restore* the entire filesystem from this backup, as permissions would have to be reset manually for every file/directory.

PLEASE NOTE that you should NEVER use this directory in anything but a dire case, such as the need to recover files when a WSL installation is completely borked.  Accessing these files through Windows can result in a corrupted WSL installation [according to Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

Comment: After failing through multiple methods, your method of replacing ext4.vhdx for WSL2 worked like a charm. So simple, yet works perfectly. Thank you. Joined this community just to upvote your answer.