# I reset Ubuntu on WSL with "Setting > Apps > Ubuntu > Reset". Now all my files in WSL filesystem is lost. How can I recover it?

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtual-file-system

I am using Ubuntu on WSL2 on Windows
([OS Version Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHZKE.png)). I reset the Ubuntu app by giving:

[Settings > Apps > Apps & Features > Ubuntu > Reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohZEM.png)

Under 'uninstall' it's mentioned that uninstalling the WSL distribution doesn't affect the files, so does 'Resetting' a WSL distribution really remove the files in the WSL filesystem? I expected the /home directory files to get preserved but after reset I find that there is nothing left in /home.

Is it possible to recover the data that was there in /home?

Thanks for your time with this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly, I don't have great news for you; only perhaps a suggestion when reinstalling that will hopefully prevent it from happening again.

First up, the *Reset* option in the screenshot you posted does say specifically:

> If this app isn't working right, reset it.  The app's data will be deleted.

So yes, a *Reset* did get rid of the entire Ubuntu WSL data (the filesystem and registry data).

A *Repair*, on the other hand, keeps the WSL Ubuntu distribution intact.

**Important note:** These options, and the wording behind them in the settings, are the same for all Store apps.  I know that the *Uninstall* wording says:

> Your documents will not be affected.

However, the way WSL installations are handled, an uninstall *does* remove the entire instance.  The documents are part of the filesystem, which is removed on an uninstall.

I've seen cases where the Store apps are being reset for other reasons, resulting in WSL data loss.  For that reason (and more), I recommend the following ...

##### Preventing Uninstall and Reset from removing WSL data

I'm seriously thinking about doing my first YouTube video on this soon.  When installing Ubuntu (or any other distribution) in WSL, the first thing I do is "disconnect" the instance from the Store installation by "moving" it to its own directory.

By default, WSL distributions are installed into:

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\<DistributionPackage>\
```

This includes the virtual filesystem, either:

- WSL2: `..\<DistributionPackage>\LocalState\ext4.vhdx`
- WSL1: `..\<DistributionPackage>\LocalState\rootfs\`

For Ubuntu, that `<DistributionPackage>` name is going to start with `Canonical` and include `Ubuntu` in the name (along with other identifiers).

It's worth checking to see if that directory is still there.  If so, your data could be recoverable.  However, I don't believe it's likely.  It's more likely that, if you've rerun `ubuntu.exe` after the Reset, that it's the *new* installation that is there.

Anyway, I recommend this process for "disconnecting" the Store install so this doesn't happen again:

- Once you've installed Ubuntu and configured your username and password.
- Exit Ubuntu
- From PowerShell:

  ```
  # Confirm the distribution name
  wsl -l -v
  # Distribution name may be "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu-20.04" - Adjust the following lines accordingly:
  wsl --shutdown
  cd ~\Documents
  mkdir WSL\images
  mkdir WSL\instances\MyUbuntu
  wsl --export Ubuntu WSL\images\ubuntu_clean.tar
  wsl --import MyUbuntu WSL\instances\MyUbuntu WSL\images\ubuntu_clean.tar --version 2
  ```

  Note that most of the directory and filenames above (and the instance name) are up to you.
- You should now have two Ubuntu installations, as you can confirm with `wsl -l -v`.
- Launch the new one with `wsl -d MyUbuntu`
- `--import`ed instances don't "remember" your default username (although the user still exists).  Set the default username in that instance via a `/etc/wsl.conf` file per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833).  Specifically:

  ```
  sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
  ```

  And add the following lines:

  ```
  [user]
  default=<yourusername>
  ```
- Exit the instance
- Again, from PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --terminate MyUbuntu
  wsl --set-default MyUbuntu
  ```
- Now, the default instance is `MyUbuntu`.  It is what will launch whenever you start WSL with the `wsl` command.
- Uninstall the Store Ubuntu.  You won't have to worry about it being reset again.

If you do need to try something out in Ubuntu that you feel might cause issues, do it in a new temporary instance:

Again, in PowerShell:

```
cd ~\Documents\WSL
mkdir instances\UbuntuTest
wsl --export MyUbuntu images\current_ubuntu.tar
wsl --import UbuntuTest instances\UbuntuTest images\current_ubuntu.tar --version 2
wsl -d UbuntuTest
```

That's a separate instance that you can install in, change configuration, go wild.  When you are doing with it, exit and:

```
wsl --unregister UbuntuTest
```

This will delete that test instance, and leave `MyUbuntu` intact.

Note, of course, that the entire `UbuntuTest` instance will be gone, so make sure you don't create any documents or data that you need there longterm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time creating such a detailed answer. It really helps a lot. Like you said I had indeed rerun the Ubuntu.exe after the reset, so it's probably the new ubuntu filesystem that's sitting in '%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\' but still I attempted running file recovery in that folder with Recuva but couldn't recover any .vhdx file or rootfs folder (could 'reset' really have deleted the .vhdx file that effectively? Do you think it could be recovered?). 
A youtube video on this like you had mentioned, could get a good audience. I will try out your delink method.

Comment: @Vishnu3333 If you were truly using WSL2, then it would be the `.vhdx`, and in my experience, recovering files that large is pretty tough.  I used to have fairly good success with Recuva when I was using magnetic storage, but really 0 success since moving to SSDs in the last few years.  On the off chance that the instance was WSL1 (I know you said WSL2, but sometimes we just get lucky) then you would probably want to look for any filename you can remember from the instance, in the vent it became disconnected from the rootfs directory after deletion.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I luckily had Acronis true image running which had a backup. Using that and your answer from https://askubuntu.com/a/1350429/662944 I simply could copy over the %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroup...\LocalState\ext4.vhdx file and it worked!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds how do you `Uninstall the Store Ubuntu`

Comment: Start menu, Right click Ubuntu, uninstall worked. You can't do it via the MS store which is weird.

Comment: @Mark Glad you found it.  Yes, it's a bit odd that "App Stores" (in general) don't allow you to uninstall from within the store.  Out of the "big 3" (being Apple, Microsoft, and Google Play), only Google Play gives you an uninstall option *in the store*.  I've honestly never thought about it before, but it would make more sense to have an "Uninstall" option in the same place that you originally "Install"ed something :-).  As a side note, Windows apps which were installed from the Microsoft Store can *also* be uninstalled in *Settings* -> *Apps* -> *Apps & Features*.