# WSL 2 overwrite original WSL 2 distribution files?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was facing issues with Ubuntu and decided to uninstall the program, through the Windows Start menu. I then ran "wsl --install" and "wsl --install -d Ubuntu" in PowerShell. I noticed when going back into Ubuntu it made me make a new account, and my original files at ~\ and bash aliases were missing. Is there any way to recover these files from the previous install of Ubuntu?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very unlikely.  While the Windows "Uninstall" option on apps says that it will leave your data, that's not true for the WSL distributions, at least not under Windows 10.  I believe this has changed under Windows 11.  To prevent this from happening again, though, please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390026/1165986) where I run through how to "disconnect" the distribution from the Store App.

Comment: So I believe I ran those same commands to install wsl originally, instead of going through the Microsoft Store. So I believe it wasn’t a Store App to begin with. Would this make any difference?

Comment: I read the directions in your linked post and it looks like the Ubuntu package folder is new, meaning my old one is gone. A follow up verification would be appreciated, but it looks like I’ll be starting fresh. Thank you for the linked post so I can avoid this issue in the future.